# jQuery: adding css depending on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check the height of an image (there are multiple such elements on a page). If the height is greater than 66px, I want to apply a negative top margin equal to half of its height.

The following code doesn't do anything. What is wrong with my if statement?

```
if($('.topstories a.image img').height() > 66){
    var margintop = -0.5 * ($(this).height() - 66);
    $(this).css('margin-top', 'margintop');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the rest of your function, but you to go through each image, you'll need to use a loop or each(). Something like:

```
$('.topstories a.image img').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 66)){
        var margintop = 0.5 * ($(this).height());
        $(this).css('margin-top', '-' + margintop);
    }
});
```

I'm thinking that your subtraction of 66 in the math operator also is causing an issue - if the image height is 67, and you subtract 66, you get 1. 1 * .5 sort of equals 0, so you wouldn't see an effect.

Answer (score 4):

You've put the value to margintop in quotes, so it's treated as a string literal (an invalid value in this case). Try:

```
$(this).css('margin-top', margintop);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're applying the style to the correct element? What is `this` in this context? Have you tried specifying the selector in place of this? Something like $("#idOfImage").css('margin-top', margintop);

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$(this).css('margin-top', 'margintop');
```

with

```
$(this).css('margin-top', margintop);
```